# It is possible to grab process memory using ftrace?

Tags: linux, trace, ptrace, procfs, ftrace

I have two applications one writing requests to and reading responses from stdin/stdout of another. I should not modify the applications, but I have root permission. I need to intercept requests, and responses and measure time when some messages passed as precise as possible.

Currently I'm using ptrace, trace read and write syscalls on `fd=0` and `fd=1` and grab memory from `/proc/<pid>/mem`, but the overhead is too big, we cannot use such imprecise timestamps. I'm trying to use ftrace, but, I cannot read from `/proc/<pid>/mem`, because ftrace doesn't stop the tracee application.

It seems, ftrace only give me arguments of functions and registers, but I cannot google how to grab the buffer at the pointer given as argument. Is it even possible?

Could you suggest another approach for my problem?

Comment: Can't you just interpose yourself between the two processes? i.e. basically act like `tee`, but record information about timing, etc. See the [example code for the `tee` system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/tee.2.html) for a way to combine `tee()` and `splice()` to be able to move the data with low overhead (which you can read later, or in a different thread or process).

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks, I did not know about tee. I will try. But it is only first step, I also (will) need to intercept network tcp communication. So I anyway will need ptrace/ebpf/ftrace, and I hope ftrace can be helpful.